# AJAX: Can an attacker manipulate returned JSON?

Tags: ajax, json

I'm creating an internal web application. While security is not a big concern, I still have a question. If a web page makes an AJAX call, the server does its thing and returns JSON data and then the data is interpreted and displayed by the browser. Can an attacker modify this jSON data before it reaches the client (eg. is interpreted by web page script)?

I presume yes? (no ssl or so, plain JSON)

Comment: And where is attacker? Between web server and client?

Comment: it is simple, you have to assume that any response can be faked. Have a look at fiddler, its perfect example, injection responses etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course he can! A much simpler way would be to change the request URL to a page he is managing.
Don't forget that javascript is run **client side**. So there's little to worry about.

---

Zerkms' comment does makes some sense. If you are asking if a hacker can modify data between a server and **another** client, that's a yes if the hacker has access to the client's network OR access to the server's network.

That's where SSL comes in.

Comment: An abstract answer to an abstract question. So helpful! ;-)